# Replace Atlassian and JFrog with open source alternatives?

Tags: artifactory, jira

1. Are there open source alternatives to Atlassian suite (Jira, Confluence, Bitbucket, etc) and JFrog (Artifactory, etc) that you have found satisfactory?
2. What general steps did you take to migrate to the open source versions of these suites?